# Changing the text in a textBox defined inside data template of datagrid on a button click

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working in silverlight.
i have a textbox inside the datagrid and i have a button on my page whose function is to surround the selected text with brackets. eg. let the text in my textbox be "Hello World", now when my datagrid will enter into editing mode , i want to  select some text from this textbox. let it be "World". now i have selected "world" and when i click the button, the output in the textbox should be " Hello (World)" . 
but the problem is when i select the text and click on button, the textbox loses focus and the text remains unchanged. and in case if i focus the textbox , then button doesn't get clicked.

Please can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use client events ?
You can take a look at JQuery's Caret plugin:
http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php

```
// Get start position in textbox box with id="textbox1"
$("#textbox1").caret().start

// Get end position in textbox
$("#textbox1").caret().end

// Get selected text in textbox
$("#textbox1").caret().text
```

There is also the simple Javascript solution:

```
<script language=javascript>
function getSelText()
{
var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection)
    {
        txt = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection)
    {
        txt = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    else return;
document.aform.selectedtext.value =  txt;
}
</script>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Get selection" onmousedown="getSelText()"> 
    <form name=aform >
    <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>
```

Source : http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp

Comment: Actually i need to make changes in code behind and cannot use javascript.

Comment: can you use textBox1.SelectionStart and textBox1.SelectionLength ? 
You could use these with the LostFocus event to store the value temporarily

Comment: yes.. i have already stored the selected text but the problem is on making changes in the text, changes are not reflected in the DataGrid.